# How to Get the separate value of dynamically created textarea jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
 <table class="cssTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea id="txtOption1" cols="30" rows="2">Text1</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table  class="cssTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea id="txtOption2" cols="30" rows="2">Text2</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" OnClientClick="ClickMe();" Text="Submit" />
```

I try this to get the value of textarea separate:

```
function ClickMe() {
        $(".cssTable").each(function () {                
            alert($("[Id*=txtOption]").text());
        });
    }
```

but getting the both text as **text1text2**  both time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify the context

```
function ClickMe() {
    $(".cssTable").each(function () {                
        alert($("[Id*=txtOption]",this).text());
       // eventually the same as $(this).find('[Id*=txtOption]')
    });
}
```

Though you should be using .val() to get the value of textarea

```
alert($("[Id*=txtOption]",this).val());
```